# calling script when click button

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a program, this is the simple idea of it. First i run main_window.py it will open sub_window.py this sub_window have 2 buttons Run and Stop.

When i click Run button i need to run hello.py script and close Sub Window GUI same as when i clicked stop i need to stop hello.py script and close Sub Window GUI.

my current code gives me "NameError: name 'Dialog' is not defined" error.

this is main_window.py code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sub_window

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def sub(self):
        self.subwin = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui =  sub_window.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.subwin)  
        self.subwin.show()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(397, 157)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnClick = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnClick.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 161, 51))
        self.btnClick.setObjectName("btnClick")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        ################### Butten Event ##################################
        self.btnClick.clicked.connect(self.sub)


        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Window"))
        self.btnClick.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Click"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is sub_window.py code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def funRun(self):
        Dialog.hide()
        exec(open("hello.py").read())

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(332, 108)
        self.btnRun = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btnRun.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 101, 31))
        self.btnRun.setObjectName("btnRun")
        self.btnStop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btnStop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 40, 101, 31))
        self.btnStop.setObjectName("btnStop")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        ################### Butten Event ##################################
        self.btnRun.clicked.connect(self.funRun)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Sub Window"))
        self.btnRun.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Run"))
        self.btnStop.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Stop"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is hello.py code

```
import time

while True:
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not modify the .py generated by pyuic as indicated by the warning of the generated file and [the docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) so you have to restore those files by running the pyuic command again.

Considering the above, then you must create a main.py where the logic is implemented. On the other hand it is not considered good practice to use `exec()` so in that case you must modify "hello.py" so that the infinite loop is encapsulated in a function. You also have to keep in mind that an infinite loop cannot be executed in the same GUI thread, so you must execute it in a secondary thread:

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main_window import Ui_MainWindow
from sub_window import Ui_Dialog
import threading
from hello import task


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.dialog = Dialog()
        self.btnClick.clicked.connect(self.dialog.show)


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnRun.clicked.connect(self.run)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        threading.Thread(target=task, daemon=True).start()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**hello.py**

```
import time


def task():
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

In the case that hello.py cannot be modified or `exec()` must be used then you must create a function that executes that task:

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main_window import Ui_MainWindow
from sub_window import Ui_Dialog
import threading


def task():
    with open("hello.py") as f:
        exec(f.read())


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.dialog = Dialog()
        self.btnClick.clicked.connect(self.dialog.show)


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnRun.clicked.connect(self.run)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        threading.Thread(target=task, daemon=True).start()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```